# New git repo with several revisions

Tags: git

Is there a proper way to commit multiple revisions to a new git repository?

I'm attempting to debug a serialization problem which is resulting in a specific change to my XML. For now my problem is that I don't know when it happens, so I've scheduled a timer to serialize the data every second. This produces 10s of files which I would like to quickly browse through in TortoiseGit's log window to find when the change occurred.

Of course, I could loop manually:

- rename a file to some standard name,
- commit it,
- delete it,
- repeat.

In theory, the same program which generates these files could do that, but I'm not confident enough in my git skills to run a command in a loop; I rely on instant feedback to know whether I need to repair my repo.

Is there any better way?

Comment: How about something like `git add . ; git commit -a -m ''` every second? That would add and commit all of the changes.

Comment: @nwinkler If I serialize them under the same name, that should work. On the downside, I would feel lame for not building it myself, and would still be afraid it would break. :p Pah, I can delete the folder if it gets botched, so whatever.